# Are there tools to calculate the electrical conductivity of large (>1000 atom) nanostructures?

Tags: software-recommendations, physical-properties-of-materials, nanostructures, electronic-transport

Are there any free to use tools which can be used to calculate the electrical conductivity of nanostructured materials. The systems that I am interested in consist of several thousand atoms, and running DFT calculations is not an option due to the lack of computational resources.

Are there any **tools or theoretical methods** which I can use to calculate the **electrical conductivity** of these 2D and 1D materials?

Comment: Can you be more specific what kind of methods are you looking for? MC, QMC and finite element analysis labels seems unrelevant to your question.

Comment: @Greg I have seen articles where MC, QMC and finite element analysis have been used to estimate electrical conductivity in nanowires and carbon nanotube composites. My specific requirement is to reduce the computational power required to estimate the electrical conductivity of these structures since it is not achievable using DFT methods (based on available resources).

Comment: I doubt you would have resources for a QMC calulation when you do not have for DFT, therefore it is misleading.

Comment: Any idea of a less resource intensive method?

Comment: Did you put the tags there? It isn't completely clear what you are requesting + the forcefully tags? I.e. one can calculate the AHC in fairly large tight-binding models, but it isn't clear either whether this is the path. I think overall it needs more context exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: @nickpapior I put the tags there by selecting from existing tags. What I needed is a tool/method which requires significantly less computational resources compared to DFT to calculate the electrical conductivity of the nanostructures consisting of several thousand atoms.

Comment: Can you parameterise a tight-binding Hamiltonian? You could use something like KITE, but it might need a *lot* of RAM. https://quantum-kite.com/

Comment: @PhilHasnip thanks for the idea, but I am limited to only 16GB of ram. I don't suppose that would be sufficient right?

Comment: I don't actually know, it depends how many sites you have and what energy resolution you need. The state-of-the-art calculations (a billion atoms/1 meV resolution for graphene) use several terabytes (!) but I assume you don't need that kind of scale...?

Comment: @PBH You could ask a question about the RAM usage on the main site and might get a bigger audience that way.

Comment: @PhilHasnip no, I do not need that sort of computation. I'll anyway give KITE a try to see if my available resources can handle the problem. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Have you figured out the answer now PBH? Please update us! It would be nice to get this out of the unanswered queue now that it's been more than 8 months!

Comment: @NikeDattani no. It seems that there are no feasible tools to do the job. The Tight Binding approach seems to be a good way to go. However, I decided to skip this portion of the study as starting from scratch on tight binding calculations would consume more time than I could afford.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of detailed considerations when computing electronic transport, but in general the answer is "yes", *provided* you can calculate (or estimate) a model Hamiltonian. For example, a DFT calculation may be used to compute the parameters for a model tight-binding Hamiltonian (e.g. using a local basis set, or Wannier90) which can then be used for much larger transport calculations.

Many studies use the (linearised) Boltzmann Transport Equations (BTE), for example as implemented in [BoltzTraP2](https://gitlab.com/sousaw/BoltzTraP2) or [BoltzWann](https://www.wannier.org). A more sophisticated approach is to solve the quantum transport problem directly from the tight-binding Hamiltonian, for example the [Quantum Kite](https://quantum-kite.com) software of my colleague Aires Ferreira and coworkers.

Although a few thousand atoms would usually require a small computer cluster for DFT (depending on the basis set), the tight-binding Hamiltonian can be solved much more quickly. A common limiting factor is computer RAM, and you may need to invest in more RAM to perform large calculations.

These methods typically give you the electrical conductivity *per unit of time*; the actual conductivity will depend on how long it takes for conduction electrons to relax back down to the (non-conducting) valence state, which is called the "relaxation time". The main factor affecting this is usually the electron-phonon interaction, but calculating that is computationally intensive. The common method is to use DFT, but this will not be practical for your situation; even if you did have the computational resources for a DFT calculation, an $N$-atom system has $3N$ phonons, and you need one DFT calculation for each phonon!

It may be possible to estimate the relaxation time, for example by calculating it for a prototypical bulk system (which has far fewer atoms), or by using acoustic deformation potential theory. Even if you do not know the relaxation time, you can still investigate differences in conductivity per unit time, and if you assume that the relaxation time is similar across the various structures then this trend should be reflected in the actual conductivity.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Take a look at SIESTA: the "Spanish Initiative for Electronic Simulations with Thousands of Atoms". Love that name.

It is much more efficient than the plane-wave DFT codes for this type of calculation, since it considers wavefunctions using a tight-binding basis and exploits matrix sparsity.

I have not used it, but another student in my group has. It still took a while to converge the wavefunctions and atomic positions for a massive supercell, but it is worth a cursory glance. Especially if you are simply inputting the atomic positions, converging the wavefunctions, and running very simple landauer transport.

Depending on your supercell/atomic complexity, you might alternatively be able to construct a simple tight-binding model and build up green's functions and electrodes to model transport. Take a look at Supriyo Datta's course on nanohub.

Out of curiosity, what is the system you are trying to consider? I understand if you don't want to answer.

Comment: I am looking at nanoparticle based structures such as the ones studied [here](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/5.0060487).

Comment: Okay. So in general yes, though this might be kind of hard. SIESTA / transiesta might be the way to go for some simple test systems, but you should see how those scale. You should also ask if you want to consider an infinite chain of nanoparticles, or a finite chain of nanoparticles with solid electrodes at either end. The latter would be more doable with a home-built NEGF transport code or Kwant if you are okay with a simple model.

How realistic do you want this? transiesta can model IV curves and temperature, though it would be inherently computationally intensive.